# Can I take a list of Titles from a Content Type and turn them into a Taxonomy list?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type called Instructor Profiles. The title field is their name. Can I use a list of this Title field and make a Taxonomy list. Is there a way to keep a list synchronised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it looks like I can with [Node Auto Term [NAT]](https://drupal.org/project/nat)

> Node Auto Term or NAT is a helper module used to facilitate node-node
>   relationships through the use of the Taxonomy module; i.e. when a node
>   is created, a taxonomy term is also created automatically using its
>   title and body in any associated vocabularies. Other nodes can now be
>   tagged with terms from these vocabularies thereby establishing
>   node-node relationships.

Comment: Please avoid short answers that contain only a link.

Comment: Scott, good point. Thanks for adding that description. It was a hurried day.